# DNS to \\Server\ wrong - \\Server.company.local\ works fine

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, shares

I had a little network glitch and since then one of my servers shows up wrong at some workstations when typing in `\\server\`.

Example:

On workstationA I go to Explorer and and type `\\server\` and it brings me to our copier at 192.168.2.101. `\\server.company.local\` gets me to the right place at 192.168.2.252.

Ping with `server` pings 192.168.2.252 - same correct result with ping server.company.com
nslookup also shows correct result with both. reverse lookup by ip is correct also.

I flush the DNS on the workstation and the error still occurs. reboot same result.

At that point I give up and start remapping the shares to `\\server.company.local\share` just to get the user back working...

DNS Server has correct entries for that server. Can access the server via `\\server\` on dns server, all looks fine.

Eventually the workstation figures it out by itself and `\\server\` works again but my life wouldn't be as stressful if I had a clue what happened or how to fix it myself.

*Thanks for your time looking and answering.*

Comment: what does this command return when run from a command prompt on Workstation A?     nbtstat -an servername

Comment: @Tatas - I wish I had a failing workstation right now :) - I posted after the last one magically fixed itself after I remapped a bunch of shares manually.

_I will brush up on WINS_ and certainly check out nbtstat results along with flushing that cache to see if it solves upper problem.

Comment: nbtstat -an server returns: `C:\Documents and Settings\alice>nbtstat -an server Local Area Connection: Node IpAddress: [192.168.2.54] Scope Id: [] NetBIOS Remote Machine Name Table Name Type Status --------------------------------------------- SERVER <00> UNIQUE Registered MCO <00> GROUP Registered MCO <1E> GROUP Registered MAC Address = 00-0C-29-7F-15-17`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling NetBIOS name resolution.

Network adapter properties -> TCP/IP properties -> Advanced -> WINS tab -> Disable NetBIOS over TCP/IP

[image]

Strip out any WINS config, too, and make sure you aren't getting a WINS server configured by DHCP.

Comment: Man that is scary. Are you that certain that he doesn't have a dependent service that cares about NetBIOS. That could be some seriously bad advice for some networks.

Comment: @Mark He's doing the name resolution from a workstation, not a server.  So no, I'm not too terribly worried about the consequences of making that change on the workstation.

Comment: Disabling netbios over TCPIP did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

You're possibly confusing WINS and DNS.

\server\share

uses a WINS entry which holds the NETBIOS name to IP mapping

\server.company.local\share

uses a DNS entry which holds the FQDN (Fully Qualified Domain Name) to IP mapping

If you're running a local WINS server, you'll want to rectify the issue you have with the server's netbios name entry.  You can manually modify the record, or just delete it and run the following command from the command prompt on your server.

nbtstat -RR

If you're not running a WINS service on your network, then you can disable it as the other answer has described.  WINS is a legacy windows service that would store and serve up NETBIOS names on your network.  DNS is a domain name resolution service that stores and serves up records which hold the FQDN (Fully Qualified Domain Names, such as www.microsoft.com) to IP mapping, or vice versa.  There are other records that it can host, but these are the main two that most people need to know about.

Comment: A single-name entry can be resolved via DNS search suffix, WINS is not necessarily used in all situations.

Comment: Agreed.  It could be possible that the search suffixes are different on these hosts.  It's why I added the comment above to see what gets returned from an NBTSTAT.

Comment: Completely missed that!  Good point.

Comment: NP.  It's hard to troubleshoot these things when you have no idea what someone elses network is like.

Comment: nbtstat -RR does nothing :(